# display flex gave the images and full paragraph horizontally but not working

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive-design

I have no idea why my website cannot display to change flex (I mean, some element of text on the left side and the images on the right side), why it's not working?

```css
.presentation {
  display: flex;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  min-height: 80vh;
  align-items: center;
}

.introduction {
  flex: 1;
}

.cover img {
  height: 60vh;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section class="presentation">
    <div class="introduction">

      <!--intro text..., -->
      <div class="intro-text">
        <h1>mac</h1>
        <p>This is the latest laptop and this laptop is the best ever until nobody doubt that want to mac. This is very powerfull, strong and almost 8k</p>
      </div>

      <!--button ...,-->
      <div class="cta">
        <button class="cta-select">14-inch</button>
        <button class="cta-add">Add Cart</button>
      </div>

      <!-- and images of laptop -->
      <div class="cover">
        <img src="https://bhrigu.me/images/mac.png" alt="laptop mac">
      </div>

    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: And the desired result is?

Answer (score 1):

You have mistakenly used `flex` property in root directory. Which elements you want to apply flex property/display, you have to use `flex` property immediate on parent div.

For example:

You have to put flex on `intro-text` class.

CSS:

```
.intro-text {
    display: flex; 
}
```

```
<div class="intro-text">
      <!--button ...,-->
      <div class="cta">
           <button class="cta-select">14-inch</button>
           <button class="cta-add">Add Cart</button>
      </div>

      <!-- and images of laptop -->
     <div class="cover">
         <img src="https://bhrigu.me/images/mac.png" alt="laptop mac">
     </div>
</div>
```

And if you want to place an element in the right position. Just use

```
.cover {
   margin-left: auto;
}
```

Please take a look here:

https://codepen.io/ilazycoder/pen/jOWQvYj